# Passing bitmap from listview adapter to fragment strange behaviour

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, bitmap

I'm getting some strange behaviour when passing a bitmap from a network image view in a listview to a fragment.

I load the image from the url in the listview adapter, then when the listview item is tapped, the image from that listview is then used as the background in the fragment. However when i do this the wrong image is displayed in the fragment, the image shown is the item from the bottom of the listview currently visible on the screen.

Here is my adapter setting the listview:

```
public class EventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
public static ArrayList<EventObject> eventList;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Bitmap bitmap;
private NetworkImageView img_main;
private RelativeLayout layoutItem;
private TextView txt_event_name;
private TextView txt_event_details;

public EventListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.eventList = eventList;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}


public void addItems(ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
    this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return eventList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@SuppressLint("all")
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    try {
        // reuse of convertView
        if (convertView == null) {
            layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_event_list_item, parent, false);
        } else {
            layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
        }

        img_main = (NetworkImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.img_main);
        txt_event_details = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_details);
        txt_event_name = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_name);

        txt_event_name.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansRegular(context));
        txt_event_details.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));

        img_main.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_weekends_matter_black);
        img_main.setImageUrl(eventList.get(position).getImageUrl(), new ImageLoader(NetworkManager.getInstance().requestQueue, new LruBitmapCache()));

        txt_event_name.setText(eventList.get(position).getEventName());
        txt_event_details.setText(eventList.get(position).getVenueName() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventList.get(position).getEventDate()));

        layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ((HomeActivity) context).setEventProfileFrag(eventList.get(position).getFullJsonObject(), ((BitmapDrawable)img_main.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
            }
        });

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    notifyDataSetChanged();
    return layoutItem;
}

private String getFormattedDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {

    //"2016-06-27 16:00:00"
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK);
    Date newDate = format.parse(dateString);

    format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM", Locale.UK);
    String date = format.format(newDate);

    return date;
}
}
```

Then finally in the fragment i retrieve the image from the arguments passed in to the fragment:

```
 mParam2 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getArguments().getByteArray(ARG_PARAM2), 0, getArguments().getByteArray(ARG_PARAM2).length);

img_header.setImageBitmap(mParam2);
```

Comment: Show your adapter class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your adapter class with below, it might work:

```
 public class EventListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      Context context;
      public static ArrayList<EventObject> eventList;
      private LayoutInflater mInflater;
      private Bitmap bitmap;
      private NetworkImageView img_main;

      class ViewHolder{

      private RelativeLayout layoutItem;
      private TextView txt_event_name;
      private TextView txt_event_details;
      }

      public EventListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
         this.context = context;
          this.eventList = eventList;
          mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       }


       public void addItems(ArrayList<EventObject> eventList) {
this.eventList.addAll(eventList);
notifyDataSetChanged();
 }

       @Override
        public int getCount() {
return eventList.size();
}

       @Override
   public Object getItem(int position) {
return eventList.get(position);
}

  @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
return 0;
}

   @SuppressLint("all")
   @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
try {
    // reuse of convertView
    ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_event_list_item, parent, false);
    } else {
        holder.layoutItem = (RelativeLayout) convertView;
    }

    holder.img_main = (NetworkImageView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.img_main);
    holder.txt_event_details = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_details);
    holder.txt_event_name = (TextView) layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.txt_event_name);

    holder.txt_event_name.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansRegular(context));
    txt_event_details.setTypeface(FontClass.getOpenSansLight(context));

        holder.img_main.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.ic_weekends_matter_black);
    holder.img_main.setImageUrl(eventList.get(position).getImageUrl(), new ImageLoader(NetworkManager.getInstance().requestQueue, new LruBitmapCache()));

    holder.txt_event_name.setText(eventList.get(position).getEventName());
    holder.txt_event_details.setText(eventList.get(position).getVenueName() + ", " + getFormattedDate(eventList.get(position).getEventDate()));

    holder.layoutItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ((HomeActivity) context).setEventProfileFrag(eventList.get(holder.getPosition()).getFullJsonObject(), ((BitmapDrawable)img_main.getDrawable()).getBitmap());
        }
    });

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

notifyDataSetChanged();
return layoutItem;
}

 private String getFormattedDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {

//"2016-06-27 16:00:00"
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.UK);
Date newDate = format.parse(dateString);

format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMMM", Locale.UK);
String date = format.format(newDate);

return date;
}
}
```

Comment: it took some refactoring to get it working but it works like a charm, thanks!